# define coding standard in struts 2

Tags: struts2

I need coding standards Struts 2 more than 20 points how to use effectively in Struts 2

1. Only using struts tags:

   We are using only Struts tags

   ```
   <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
   <html>
       <head>
       </head>
       <body>
           <h1>Struts 2 - textbox example</h1>             
           <s:form action="registerUser" namespace="/user">             
               <s:textfield key="username" />
               <s:submit key="submit" name="submit" />         
           </s:form>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. Use image heights and widths

   ```
   <img src="images/mine.gif" border="0" alt="my image" 
            width="125" height="250"/>
   ```
3. CSS Shrinker
   a. White spaces
   b. Line breaks
   c. Remove unnecessary character
   d. Depending on your level of compression
4. Eliminate Unnecessary Plugins
5. Enable browser caching
6. Turn on Gzip compression
7. Keep CSS file at top of your page and java script code at the bottom
8. Delete unnecessary element from the page
9. Remove excess white space from your coding

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Closevoted off-topic by mistake, it should be closevoted because too-broad or primarly opinion based.